# Access to custom fields in match() function of a Rule Plugin

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I try to build a Rule plugin, that checks a custom field of a product.

I do not know where to start here. How can I get access to the product object and the custom fields from inside the `match()` function of a `class` that extends `Shopware\Core\Framework\Rule\Rule`

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation on how to add a custom rule condition](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/v6.3/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/rule/add-custom-rules).

For reference on how to access the custom fields within the `Rule` extension, see [`LineItemCustomFieldRule`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/95c05031a0275fd68f3e9b7abc46dd5b664470b5/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/Rule/LineItemCustomFieldRule.php#L17).

Within the `match` method check that the scope is either an instance of `LineItemScope` or `CartRuleScope`. In case of `CartRuleScope` you can iterate the line items in the cart.

The custom fields are stored within the payload of the line items.

Generalized example to match a specific custom field within the `match` method:

```php
if ($scope instanceof LineItemScope) {
    $customFields = $scope->getLineItem()->getPayloadValue('customFields');

    return $this->customFieldMatches($customFields['my_custom_field'] ?? null);
}

if (!$scope instanceof CartRuleScope) {
    return false;
}

foreach ($scope->getCart()->getLineItems()->filterGoodsFlat() as $lineItem) {
    $customFields = $lineItem->getPayloadValue('customFields');
    if ($this->customFieldMatches($customFields['my_custom_field'] ?? null)) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Obviously `customFieldMatches` is what you would have to implement yourself with the logic that denotes whether a condition is met or not.

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt. Unfortunately for my decision making I need the product Id from the Request() of a product details page, that is not part of the available `$scope`. As Soner Sayakci comments in [NEXT-9347](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-9347) it is not possible to access data outside the given `$scope`. Looks like I'm stuck here.